# Como mover, rotacionar ou escalonar um object no seu eixo local no OpenGL?

Tags: c, c++, matriz, engine, opengl

Olá, tenho uma classe `HTransform` que armazena uma matriz, posição, orientação e escala de cada objeto, essa classe é a classe base de cada object ou entidade. Eu fiz uma função para mover os object e outra para atualizar a matriz quando a posição, rotação ou escala forem modificados. Mas isso ocorre globalmente. Mas como mover, rotacionar ou escalonar um objeto ao longo do seu próprio eixo utilizando matrizes no OpenGL?

Comment: Qual versão do OpenGL?

Comment: Tem que ser para OpenGL 1.3

Comment: Eu recomendo fortemente a biblioteca `glm`: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html

Comment: Para 1.3, acho que a `glm` não deve ser muito útil.

Comment: Então, até um tempo atrás, eu tentei usar o glm. Mas eu tive dificuldade para rotacionar os objetos com glm. Achei um pouco complicado.

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma, eu gostaria de aprender a fazer isso utilizando minhas próprias matrizes. Eu pesquisei muito mas não estou conseguindo encontrar uma resposta.

Comment: Mas você como fazer com GLM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, as matrizes que vc cita lhe permite configurar, corretamente, o objeto no sistema global. Provavelmente, vc está, primeiramente, escalonando, depois rotacionando e por fim, transladando. Vou chamar isso de transformação global

Tem várias formas de resolver o seu problema. Uma delas, é aplicar as transformações locais que vc deseja, antes de aplicar as transformações globais. Por exemplo, se deseja que o objeto rotacione em torno de seu eixo, aplica a matrix de rotação e depois aplique a matrix de transformação global.

Se vc, por algum motivo, não consegue recuperar o objeto antes das transformações globais, vc pode aplicar a inversa dessas matrizes, para recuperar o sistema local do objeto. Realiza as transformações locais e reaplica as transformações globais, novamente.

Exemplo Mglobal = T.R.S, Mglobal_inversa = S⁻¹.R⁻¹.T⁻¹, portanto
P' = Mglobal.Mlocal.Mgloval_inversa.P

Comment: Tomás Badan, massa. Mas vamos supor que eu tenha na minha classe base HTransform as seguintes variáveis: m_Position; m_Orientation; m_Scaling; m_LocalPosition; m_LocalOrientation; m_localScaling; Eu teria que aplicar tipo exemplo: MGlobal.rotate(m_Orientation); MLocal.rotate(m_LocalOrientation); Depois. MTotal = MGlobal * MLocal * MGlobal.inverse(); Isso?. É que eu estou lincando a minha engine em Lua script para que eu possa acessar depois via script.

Comment: Como a sua malha já está em coordenadas locais, aplica primeiro as transformações locais e depois as globais. Ou seja, MTotal = MGlobal.MLocal. A ideia de aplicar a reversa é para o caso que vc não tem mais a coordenada local disponível.

Comment: Tomás, obrigado me ajudou bastante. Se não for pedir muito, tipo: Eu ainda não sei como aplicar posição, rotação, escala ambas global e local na matriz do objeto. Já faz um bom tempo que eu pesquiso a procura de algo assim mas não consigo achar um resposta.

Comment: A matriz final é a multiplicação das transformações lidas da direita para a esquerda. Ou seja, Mfinal = MTglobal*MRglobal*MSglobal*MTlocal*MRlocal*MSlocal. Como tá usando o openGL 1.3, na programação, vc especifica como lê, ou seja, glTranslate(global); glRotate(global); glScale(global); glTranslate(local); glRotate(local); glScale(local); Espero qeu tenha sido mais claro agora

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, como você já realiza os cálculos utilizando sua própria classe `HTransform` em vez de utilizar as funções clássicas do OpenGL clássico `gltranslatef()`, `glRotatef()` , `glScalef()` e etc.

Então, basicamente, para que você possa mover, redimensionar e rotacionar um objeto utilizando sua matriz, antes você deve carregá-la no OpenGL. Para isso você utiliza:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(matrix);
```

Onde `matrix` é um ponteiro para uma matriz do tipo `GLfloat` 4x4, contendo os valores já calculados.

### Exemplo para OpenGL Clássico

Usando **[glfw](http://www.glfw.org/)**, para criar o contexto OpenGL, e **[glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html)**, para realizar os cálculos das matrizes (o que no seu caso é `HTransform`).

Considerando a classe `Quad` que simplesmente serve para desenhar um quadrado (ou o Objeto em questão):

```
#ifndef QUAD_DEFINED_HPP
#define QUAD_DEFINED_HPP

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

// Classe do Objeto
class Quad
{
public:
    // Construtor
    Quad(float w = 30.0f, float h = 30.0f) : m_width(w), m_height(h)
    {
        // carrega com matriz identidade.
        m_model = glm::mat4(1);

        // Define a cor padrão para vermelho.
        m_cores[0] = 1.0f; // [1] e [2] são zero.
    }

    // Move o objeto para x e y
    void moverPara(float x, float y)
    {
        m_model = glm::translate(m_model, glm::vec3(x, y, 0.0f));
    }

    // translada em relação ao eixo local
    void transladar(float x, float y)
    {
        m_model += glm::translate(m_model, glm::vec3(x, y, 0.0f));
    }

    // modifica a escala
    void setEscala(float x, float y)
    {
        m_model = glm::scale(m_model, glm::vec3(x, y, 1.0f));
    }

    // rotaciona
    void rotacionar(float angulo)
    {
        m_model = m_model * glm::rotate(angulo, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    }

    // modifica a cor do quadrado
    void setCor(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        m_cores[0] = static_cast<float>(r) / 255.0f;
        m_cores[1] = static_cast<float>(g) / 255.0f;
        m_cores[2] = static_cast<float>(b) / 255.0f;
    }

    void desenhar(void)
    {
        glPushMatrix();

        // define a cor do quadrado
        glColor3fv(m_cores);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        const GLfloat* matrix = reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(&m_model);
        glLoadMatrixf(matrix);

        // Desenha os vértices do quadrado
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, m_height, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(m_width, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(m_width, m_height, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(m_width, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, m_height, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
    }

private:
    // largura
    float m_width;

    // altura
    float m_height;

    // matriz
    glm::mat4 m_model;

    float m_cores[3];
};

#endif
```

E para criar a janela e etc:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "quad.hpp"

// Ajusta a tela para desenhar de forma ortogonal (2D).
void telaOrtogonal();

// Ponteiro para a janela atual.
GLFWwindow* window;

int main(void)
{
    // Inicializa a glfw.
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        // falhou
        return -1;
    }

    // Cria uma janela com um contexto de opengl
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        // falhou ao criar a janela
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Define a janela criada como o contexto atual.
    // Isso é usado para casos em que há vários
    // contextos opengl em um mesmo programa.
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // O objeto que será desenhado.
Quad quad1;
quad1.moverPara(20, 20);
quad1.setEscala(2.0f, 2.0f);

Quad quad2;
quad2.setCor(0, 0, 255);

quad2.moverPara(100, 80);
quad2.transladar(0, 20);
quad2.rotacionar(45);

    // Loop principal, rodado até que o usuário feche a janale.
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Ajusta para tela ortogonal (2D).
        telaOrtogonal();

        // Desenha os quadrados
        quad2.desenhar();
        quad1.desenhar();

        // Atualiza os buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Processa os eventos (mouse, teclado, sistema e etc).
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // Finaliza a glfw.
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

void telaOrtogonal()
{
    int width, height;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Note que as matrizes só são atualizadas nas chamadas:

```
Quad quad1;
quad1.moverPara(20, 20);
quad1.setEscala(2.0f, 2.0f);

Quad quad2;
quad2.setCor(0, 0, 255);
quad2.moverPara(100, 80);
quad2.transladar(0, 20);
quad2.rotacionar(45);
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: Resultado]

Sendo as bolas brancas adicionas depois para indicar o eixo local do objeto.

---

Para saber como as funções de `translate`, `scale`, `rotate` foram implementadas você pode ver o código-fonte da `glm`, é pura matemática. Mas, recomendo fortemente que você considere utilizar uma biblioteca especializa para os cálculos das matrizes (ou pelo menos veja o código-fonte) pois elas geralmente são bem otimizadas, testadas e a maioria utiliza otimizações do tipo SSE, SSE2, SSE3 (etc) nos cálculos das matrizes.

---

Se for possível também ao invés de utilizar OpenGL 1.3, você poderia considerar utilizar OpenGL 3.3+, pois o OpenGL 3 tornou várias funções clássicas do OpenGL obsoletas.

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela resposta. Mas o que eu quero é mover, rotacionar e escalonar um objeto no seu próprio eixo. Esse exemplo que você fez só faz transformações em eixos globais. Exemplo quad2.movePara((float x, float y), bool local), entendeu?

Comment: O `moverPara()` funciona em relação ao eixo global. O `transladar()` translada em relação ao eixo local. E a rotação já está no eixo local.

Comment: @WalbertiEvaristo Adicionei uma imagem para ilustrar o exemplo, com os eixos destacados.